# OpenVPN connection with pre-shared key RAND_bytes() failed

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

Since last upgrade (16.4.1 LTS), my openvpn client connections failed with `RAND_bytes() failed` in the log files. I am using a pre-shared key to authenticate. I use network-manager to initiate the connection. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to a chroot environment, which network-manager/openvpn is setting up for me. The environment needs a /dev/urandom, which was not present for me.
Based on [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/646), I was able to fix the problem as following:

```
cd /var/lib/openvpn/chroot
sudo mkdir dev
cd dev
sudo mknod random c 1 8
sudo mknod urandom c 1 9
```

Then, the connection should be successful again.

Answering my own question here in case anyone else has this problem